# Unity)How to use Profiler.Sample with #if UNITY_EDITOR

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

I want to run Profiler.Sample() only in Unity Editor.
However, not-matching errors occur when running in the above state.
Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Note btw from [`Profiler.BeginSample`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Profiling.Profiler.BeginSample.html): `Profiler.BeginSample is conditionally compiled away using ConditionalAttribute. Thus it will have zero overhead, when it is deployed in non-Development Build.` -> there is no need for the pre-processor